# Android - How can I go back to previous activity from layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Here I am unable to open previous activity i.e., `my_layout1` on back pressed.

This is my code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.my_layout1);
      Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.my_Layout2);
        }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Please give me suggestions on how to open previous activity layout from current layout.

Comment: This code is OK, except the fact you're forcing a `finish` from `onBackPressed`. The Activity's `onBackPressed` checks first if there are any fragments to be popped. What do you have in layout?

Comment: how are you coming from activity 1 to activity 2 are you finishing first activity , then you have to restart intent..

Comment: there is no fragment, one click on the back press go to previous activity and again one more click then close the app

Comment: Then remove `onBackPressed` since Android is doing the same thing anyway

Comment: by default i started one activity with one sample layout.. on same activity by clicking on button i started another layout.. now my question is on first time back pressed how can i go to previous  lay out?

Comment: @mvnpavan i have only one activity ...

Answer (score 0):

When you press back you are finishing current activity with all layouts on it. In on back press you should create new intent and start this activity. Or

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout1);
```

Comment: by default i started one activity with one sample layout.. on same activity by clicking on button i started another layout.. now my question is on first time back pressed how can i go to previous  lay out?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have just 1 activity here, not 2. Calling setContentView again in your onClick does not create a new activity or add anything to the backstack. So when you click back, or call finish(), the activity simply ends.

If you want to dynamically inflate various layers within an activity, look into using fragments (you can add fragments to the back stack to get the result you want when pressing back). However the easier option is to navigate to another activity class in your onClick (via an intent) in which you inflate my_Layout2.

So create another activity class (e.g. Main2) similar to this one in which you inflate my_Layout2 (don't forget to register Main2 it in the manifest). Then from your onClick in Main:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Main2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I don't know why you had the -1 downvote because it seems you are the only one who understood Maneti correctly. As far as I have understood him he has 1 Activity whose layout he changed with a click on a button instead of opening a new Activity.

Answer (score 0):

In `onBackPressed` instead of finishing the activity change your layout to `my_layout1`.

Declare a global variable `int count=0;`

In your `onClick` add this line `count=0;`

Change your `onBackPressed` like this:

```
 @Override   
 public void onBackPressed() {
  if(count==0){
    ++count;
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout1);
  }
  else
  finish();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to go back to previous activity set `flagLayoutControl` as `true` and then write below code

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    // pass to if back is pressed     
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        if(flagLayoutControl)
        {
              Intent myIntent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, <<WhatYouWant>>.class);
              startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
          finish(); 
        }
        else
        {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, currentActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish(); 

        }

        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a button and Try this:

@Override

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

   onBackPressed();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override  
public void onBackPressed()   
{  
   super.onBackPressed();
   startActivity(new Intent(my_Layout2.this, my_layout1 .class));
   my_Layout2.this.finish();         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.my_Layout2);
    }
```

Use this

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.finish();
    }
```

This close your current layout and show the top most layout

Answer (score -1):

please use below code

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
{  
     //replaces the default 'Back' button action  
     if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)  
     {  

       finish(); 
     return true;  
   }
```

Comment: He doesn't have two activity but two layouts. You didn't get the question right.

Comment: give finish () while clicking of backbutton

Answer (score -1):

Put it on back button click.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main Class.this, 
Name of classactivity on which you want to go.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: No need to put intent over there because android manage back operation it self.